# The PUM project vs PUM project

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I got stuck with the one very classic problems of English - articles. Don't get me wrong, I'm pretty decent and English and mostly use them automatically in the proper position (I hope so).
However, when I start thinking about it, I often get confused. I came across a situation when I'm constantly getting corrected by text editors. When I write

> Thank you for the work in PUM project.

Editors usually wants to make it

> Thank you for the work in **the** PUM project.

Why is that so? I always thought I don't need to use definite article before names (with exceptions of course).

P.S. I would also appriciate some good material on articles.

Comment: You usually work **on** a project, not *in* it.

Comment: I don't know what PUM stands for, but I would expect a project to be called _the X Project_, meaning 'the project for doing X'.

Comment: That doesn't sound exactly right: "don't need to use definite article before names".   I want to visit **the** Empire State Building.  Let's go to **the** Beacon Theatre.   I will work on  **the** X project.